# Angular, delay of initial load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a generator here - https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack, and I am having a small problem when it initially loads.

There is a second or 2 when it loads when you can see the index.html template without partial css on it, and then it loads the user to the login page. I would like to get rid of this, so when you go to the root, you would go straight to /login. I'm not sure where to begin with this, as it could be many things. I should not I have alot of bower'd in scripts, maybe they are slowing this down?

My first thought was it was the authentication, but maybe it has nothing to do with it. But here is the app js minus the dependancies

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
 })

.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
return {
  // Add authorization token to headers
  request: function (config) {
    config.headers = config.headers || {};
    if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
    }
    return config;
  },

  // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
  responseError: function(response) {
    if(response.status === 401) {
      $location.path('/login');
      // remove any stale tokens
      $cookieStore.remove('token');
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
    else {
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  }
};
})

 .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
// Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
  Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
    if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
      $location.path('/login');
    }
  });
});
});
```

It could entirely not be this, but I think it might be. I don't care if the page is blank for second, but it's showing the items in the top like the header menu that is in the base index.html with a little css styling on it, but it looks terrible. Any direction in where to look to fix this would be MUCH appreciated, as I have no idea where to even start.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: u can solve it on server side easily

Comment: read up on how to use `ng-cloak` in angular docs